Remove an entire inner list that has any zeros
I have a list:
IntegerDigits[Range[3434, 3455]]

{{3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 3, 
  8}, {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 
  4, 3}, {3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 4, 7}, {3, 
  4, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 0}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 
  2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}}

I want to remove any inner list that has zeros (in any position) in it:  {3, 4, 5, 0} and {3, 4, 4, 0}
This method only removes the 0 itself from the list:
DeleteCases[IntegerDigits[Range[3434, 3455]], 0, Infinity]

It results in the reduction of the 2 that I want removed (plus the others intact):
-->  {3, 4, 4} , {3, 4, 5}

It is also similar to Removing zero values from ordered pairs (asked 11 years ago!)

One possible way
 Select[lis, Not[MemberQ[#, 0]] &]

Where lis is your original list.
Or
Select[lis, FreeQ[#, 0] &]


On a diff note, how do we get rid of all the numbers with zeros in
this list? Select[Range[100, 150], FreeQ[0]] that does not work!

You could do
lis = Range[100, 150]


lis2 = IntegerDigits[lis]
lis3 = Select[lis2, FreeQ[0]]
lis4 = FromDigits[#] & /@ lis3

Gives


A bit tidier: Select[lis, FreeQ[0]]

The issue is my list is already in a Select expression.   Hence do I do a nested Select? Or can a Select have 2 different conditions? If so whats the syntax of that?

On a diff note, how do we get rid of all the numbers with zeros in this list? Select[Range[100, 150], FreeQ[0]]   that does not work!

@Steve237  I suggest you do things one step at time. No need to make things complicated. First generate the list you want, then as separate second command, apply the Select to remove the lists with zero in them.

For your second comment, I have to write code for it. Give me few minutes.

Agreed on doing things in 2 steps, but I have always been curious if a Select operation can indeed handle 2 conditions?

@Steve237 added answer for your comment to remove all numbers with zero in them.

@Steve237 If you want 2 (or more) conditions to be simultaneously selected just logical and (&&) them together

Pick[lst, Clip[MapApply[Times]@lst], 1]

(* {{3, 4, 3, 4}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 5}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 6}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 7}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 8}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 9}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 1}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 2}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 3}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 4}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 5}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 6}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 7}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 8}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 9}, 
    {3, 4, 5, 1}, 
    {3, 4, 5, 2}, 
    {3, 4, 5, 3}, 
    {3, 4, 5, 4}, 
    {3, 4, 5, 5}} *)

or
 Pick[#, MemberQ[0] /@ #, False] &[lst]


For the second problem:
Pick[#, Clip[MapApply[Times]@(IntegerDigits /@ #)], 1] &@Range[100, 150]

(* {111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 121, 122, 123, 124, 

125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 
141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149} *)

or
Pick[#, MemberQ[0] /@ (IntegerDigits /@ #), False] &[Range[100, 150]]


Notes on some codes
The standard commands for selecting parts of expressions are Cases/DeleteCases, Extract/Delete, Pick, Part, and Select (at level 1 only). With the recent-ish addition of Nothing, one can delete parts of lists with replacement, which is relevant to the OP's problem. One could also do this with the old-school Sequence[], and it wouldn't be restricted to lists; although if done inside a held expression, it can be inconvenient.
Select[] has the advantage of having a nice name. One immediately gets what it's for, from the beginning of learning Mathematica. Cases[] essentially does the same thing (outside of Datasets) but with a different selector: Select[] uses a function; Cases[] uses a pattern. For reasons I don't understand, Cases[] is usually faster than Select[]. Cases[] is also more general. So after some years of experience, I usually prefer Cases[] to Select[]. But I admit: Select[] does have a nice name. And speed is often not very important.
Part[] and Extract[] are similar, with the differences being rather long to list in detail. Extract[] works well with Position[].
Pick[] is very efficient. It's a good tool if you can generate the criteria for picking efficiently.
Replace[] can be very efficient. For general substitution, ReplaceAll[] is the appropriate choice. But people often overlook cases where Replace[] can be used instead. It took me twentysomething years to realize this. Slow learner.
When operating on lists and arrays, the efficiency of some methods can depend on whether an array is packed or not. Methods that rely on packed or tensor arrays cannot be applied to ragged arrays. In the problem at hand, we can pad the arrays out, but at some expense.
Non-packed, ragged lists
Some methods and timings. Some are taken or modified from other answers. Things to note: (1) Replace[] and DeleteCases[] are fastest, at least when a pattern is used instead of FreeQ[]. (2) Select[] is about 25% slower than Cases[], at least when the selectors are comparably fast. (3) The speed of Pick[] depends on the speed of constructing the second argument. (4) Applying Times to each sublist to multiply numbers is slow. Where Times is used in Pick, it is multiplying vectors and faster.
digs = IntegerDigits[Range[3434, 100455]];
Replace[digs, {___, 0, ___} -> Nothing, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
DeleteCases[digs, {___, 0, ___}]; // RepeatedTiming
Cases[digs, e_ /; FreeQ[e, 0]]; // RepeatedTiming
Select[digs, FreeQ[0]]; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Pick[#, 
     Fold[Times, 
       Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray@PadRight[#, Automatic, 1]]] //
       Unitize, 1] &; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Pick[#, Times @@ 
       Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray@PadRight[#, Automatic, 1]] //
       Unitize, 1] &; // RepeatedTiming
Replace[digs, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, 0] -> Nothing, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Delete[#, 
     List /@ DeleteDuplicates[
       First /@ Position[#, 0]]] &; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Extract[#, 
     Position[#, e_ /; FreeQ[e, 0], 1]] &; // RepeatedTiming
Pick[digs, Clip[MapApply[Times]@digs], 1]; // RepeatedTiming
Cases[digs, v_ /; Times @@ v != 0]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.0263695, Null}  Replace
{0.0270367, Null}  DeleteCases
{0.0384738, Null}  Cases
{0.0490675, Null}  Select
{0.0415988, Null}  Pick
{0.0406433, Null}   "
{0.0499491, Null}  slow Replace
{0.0520669, Null}  Delete
{0.0656063, Null}  Extract
{0.0636189, Null}  slow Pick
{0.0833571, Null}  slow Cases
*)

Packed arrays
For the most part, the timings are not greatly different than above, except for the first two Pick[] codes. They're quite a bit faster.
digs = Developer`ToPackedArray@IntegerDigits[Range[13434, 99455]];
Replace[digs, {___, 0, ___} -> Nothing, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
DeleteCases[digs, {___, 0, ___}]; // RepeatedTiming
Cases[digs, e_ /; FreeQ[e, 0]]; // RepeatedTiming
Select[digs, FreeQ[0]]; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Pick[#, Fold[Times, Transpose[#]] // Unitize, 
     1] &; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Pick[#, Times @@ Transpose[#] // Unitize, 
     1] &; // RepeatedTiming
Replace[digs, e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, 0] -> Nothing, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Delete[#, 
     List /@ DeleteDuplicates[
       First /@ Position[#, 0]]] &; // RepeatedTiming
digs // Extract[#, 
     Position[#, e_ /; FreeQ[e, 0], 1]] &; // RepeatedTiming
Pick[digs, Clip[MapApply[Times]@digs], 1]; // RepeatedTiming
Cases[digs, v_ /; Times @@ v != 0]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.0248096, Null}
{0.0399401, Null}
{0.0511707, Null}   Cases, slightly slower
{0.0586408, Null}   Select, slightly slower
{0.00210658, Null}  fast Pick
{0.00188749, Null}    "   "
{0.0463616, Null}
{0.0307772, Null}   Delete seems faster than on unpacked
{0.0697146, Null}
{0.0579896, Null}
{0.0865328, Null}
*)


Using ContainsNone:
alist = {{3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 
   4, 3, 8}, {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 
   2}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 
   4, 7}, {3, 4, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 0}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 
   4, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}}

Select[ContainsNone[{0}]][alist]


{{3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 3, 
  8}, {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 
  4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 4, 8}, {3, 
  4, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 
  4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}}


For the second problem:
blist = Range[100, 150];

Map[FromDigits]@*Select[ContainsNone[{0}]]@IntegerDigits@blist

or
FromDigits /@ DeleteCases[{___, 0, ___}][IntegerDigits@blist]


{111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 121, 122, 123, 124, \
125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, \
141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149}



My 2 cents
1.
ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][list, 1, FreeQ[0]] /. {x_} :> x




GroupBy[list, Times @@ # != 0 &][True]

where list is
list = {{3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 3, 8}, 
       {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 4, 3},
       {3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 4, 8},
       {3, 4, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 0}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, 
       {3, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}};


lis = {{3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 3, 8}, 
       {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 4, 3},
       {3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 4, 8},
       {3, 4, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 0}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, 
       {3, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}};


Using Cases:
Cases[lis, v_ /; Times @@ v != 0]

{
 {3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 3, 8},
 {3, 4, 3, 9}, {3, 4, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 4, 4},
 {3, 4, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 4, 9},
 {3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 5}
}

